# Sending data from Javascript to JSON PHP service

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to do CRUD operations with my Android App.
Apparently JSON & PHP is the way to do it, but I only find examples which seem outdated (Android Studio is marking most of the Objects as deprecated).
Right now I got none of them to work, but that might be because of my PHP.

Anyway: Can someone point me an up-to-date example on how to post data from my Android App to my JSON service?

Here's the PHP for my INSERT statement (which I pieced together from 2 tutorials):

```
include 'dbconn.php';

$get = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['req']));

$userID = $get->userID;
$text = $get->text;
$erstellt = $get->erstellt;

$sql = "INSERT INTO 4188647db4.status (id, userID, text, erstellt) VALUES (NULL, '$userID', '$text', '$erstellt');";

if ($connection->query($sql)) {
$msg = array("status" =>1 , "msg" => "OK");
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

$json = $msg;

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);

@mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library to implement HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work for the java part. I still can't get the POST data in my PHP, though. I tried $get = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you dont add `ID`s as null. Some DBs dont accept that, (keys cannot be null, and I am guessing ID is the table key)

Then, your PHP code appears to be correct. How are you calling this from Android? For debug reasons I suggest you start with a GET request (as the Android native browser can do that easily).

So suppose you have `192.168.0.X:80` as a local host, then go to the Android Browser and make a request there to your PHP, once you got that running, google your target android and [check what is best](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) ([HTTPConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) should be the default way to go, but stuff like okhhtp, Volley and many other can help you, if you intend to do basic HTTP, and dont care much how)